# Using $WPDB to create simple array to check against user entered value

Tags: functions, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a function that checks an entered value against a simple array of values to determine a match (or not).

```
function validate_unit_type( $result, $value ) {

    $pattern = ["U" ,"SE" ,"SHOP" ,"OFF" ,"APT" ,"CTGE" ,"DUP" ,"FY" ,"F" ,"HSE" ,"KSK" ,"MSNT" ,"MB" ,"PTHS" ,"RM" ,"SHED" ,"SITE" ,"SL" ,"STU" ,"TNHS" ,"VLLA" ,"WARD"];

    if ( !empty( $value ) && !in_array( $value, $pattern ) ) {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message']  = 'Invalid Unit Type.';
    }          

    return $result;
}
```

This works just fine.

The array values in $pattern are held in a MySQL DB table column too, and I'm trying to get the wpdb class to read these values into an array to suit the function.

```
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT unit_type from wpqi_enum_unit_type", ARRAY_A);
```

Other than adding the above (wpdb) what else do I need to add to the function so it will work?

Comment: What do you get when you echo out `var_dump( $results );`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to get the `wpdb` class to read these values into an array to suit the function

You could manually loop through the `$results` array to build the `$pattern` array, but a much simpler way is by using [`$wpdb->get_col()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_col/) to get all the values of the `unit_type` column:

```php
$pattern = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT unit_type from wpqi_enum_unit_type" );

/* Alternate version (i.e. manually loop through $results):
$pattern = array();

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT unit_type from wpqi_enum_unit_type" );

foreach ( $results as $row ) {
    $pattern[] = $row->unit_type;
}
*/
```

### Additional Code

This is just a suggestion: Instead of doing `in_array()` (in `validate_unit_type()`), you could also do like so, which uses [`$wpdb->get_var()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/):

```php
if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
    // This way, there'd be no need for the $pattern.
    $count = (int) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT COUNT(*) from wpqi_enum_unit_type
        WHERE unit_type = %s
        LIMIT 1
    ", $value ) );

    if ( $count < 1 ) {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message']  = 'Invalid Unit Type.';
    }
}
```

### Additional Note

I'm assuming that `wpqi_` is the table prefix, so instead of hard-coding it, I suggest you to use `$wpdb->prefix`. E.g.

```php
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'enum_unit_type';
$pattern = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT unit_type from $table" );
```

Comment: Using the alternate version suggested above, the `if ( !empty( $value ) && !in_array( $value, $pattern ) )` seems to fail now. That is, if the value is IN the array, the validation fails.

Comment: I updated that part, but that's really just a suggestion - the `in_array()` method would also be fine. Have you tried `get_col()` with your original code?

Comment: Yes, tried that too, and same result. Seems to fail the validation. Whole code I updated... `add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_1_1', 'validate_unit_type', 10, 4 );
    function validate_unit_type( $result, $value ) {

  global $wpdb;
  $pattern = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT unit_type from wpqi_enum_unit_type" );

        if ( !empty( $value ) && !in_array( $value, $pattern ) ) {
            $result['is_valid'] = false;
            $result['message']  = 'Invalid Unit Type.';
        }        

    return $result;
}`

Comment: I can't help you with the plugin, but if you're checking whether the unit type (`$value`) exists, then the original code in that part (`$count >= 1`) should do it. And what's the value of `var_dump( $pattern, $value );` with `get_col()`?

Comment: Sorry, when you said "alternate version", did you actually mean the one with `get_var()`? Have you tried that one?

Comment: Sorry, the top line (add_filter) is from the plugin, ignore that. The alternate version was the "manually loop through $results". Have tried both that, and the get_col version without success.

Comment: Well that's strange.. But you didn't answer my question on the `var_dump()` test. I've updated my answer though, and you can see the main part at the very top.

Comment: Ok, issue identified using `$wpdb->show_errors( true )`, and was my fault. I used the incorrect column name in the SQL. It now works! Yay... and thanks heaps.